# Can UIProgressView be inherited?

Tags: uiprogressview

Can `UIProgressView` be inherited?

I created a sub-class of `UIProgressView`; it works well.
But the console shows the following errors when the sub-class calls `[super init]` or `[super initWithFrame:frame]`:

```
<Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. 
<Error>: clip: invalid context 0x0. 
<Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0.
<Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. 
<Error>: clip: invalid context 0x0.
<Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you changing the track or progress color?